# Get Files from Subdirectory Only

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary, os.walk

Assume my file structure:

```
First_Folder
|____Second_Folder
     |___file1.txt
|____Third_Folder
     |___file2.txt
```

Using os.walk ()

```
for r, d, f in os.walk ('First_Folder'):
    if f:
        print ('File found!')
    else:
        print ('File not found.')
```

Output:

```
File not found.
File found!
File found!
```

How do I tell os.walk () to **only** look for files within the subdirectories, Second_Folder and Third_Folder?  The correct result should be:

```
File found!
File found!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an option in `os.walk` to do this, but you can check it yourself:

```
for r, d, f in os.walk ('First_Folder'):
    # We only want subdirectories.
    if r == 'First_Folder':
        continue
    if f:
        print ('File found!')
    else:
        print ('File not found.')
```

Alternatively, if you're only looking for files with a certain pattern (e.g. all .txt files), you can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html):

```
import glob
# matches *.txt files in subdirectories of "First_Folder"
files = glob.glob('First_Folder/*/*.txt')
```

Comment: I read all the options parameters from os.walk () and thought I'd missed something.  Of course, how could I forget glob? No loops needed.  Much cleaner and faster. Thank you!